# Expresso Store Stock Conditionals

Tags: expresso-store, ee2, conditionals

I know how to make the stock show as 'in stock' or 'out of stock' by using:
{if total_stock} In Stock {if:else} Out of Stock {/if}

How can I code the following:
"In stock" if we have more than 5 items available, "Low stock" if we only have 5 and under or "Out of stock" if we are sold out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to do something along the lines of:

```
{if total_stock > 5}
In Stock
{if:elseif total_stock <= 5 && total_stock != 0}
Low Stock
{if:else}
Out of Stock
{/if}
```

The [EE User Guide](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/templates/globals/conditionals.html) has all of the other operators you can use.

Comment: I edited my original to include a check that the stock is not 0